# operator semigroups with negative growth bound.

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ be a strongly continuous semigroup on a Banach space $X$, for which we assume that its growth bound $\omega_0$ is negative. Let $(A,D(A))$ be the generator of $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}.$

$\textbf{Question:}$
How does it implies that $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}\in\mathfrak{L}(X)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean $\|T(t)\| \le Me^{\omega_{0}t}$, where  $\omega_{0} < 0$. Then
$$
                 Bx=-\int_{0}^{\infty}T(t)x\,dt,\;\;\; x \in X
$$
defines a bounded linear operator on $X$ with $\|B\| \le M\frac{1}{|w_{0}|}$. And,
$$
            BAx = -\int_{0}^{\infty}T'(t)x\,dt = x,\;\;\; x \in \mathcal{D}(A).
$$
Similarly,
$$
              (T(h)-I)Bx = -\int_{0}^{\infty}(T(t+h)-T(t))x\,dt = \int_{0}^{h}T(t)x\,dt.
$$
So the following limit exists for all $x \in X$:
$$
               \lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}(T(h)-I)Bx = T(0)x = x.
$$
So, by the definition of the generator $A$, we have $Bx \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ for all $x$ and $ABx = x$. So $A^{-1}$ exists and equals $B \in \mathcal{L}(X)$.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. :)